# NOT mocking HttpClient in Angular 6 tests

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-test

I'm creating a service that loads and sends data over HTTP and I created some tests that need to use real HttpClient (NOT mocked).

So, here's how it looks like:

```
describe("My3rdPartyConnectedServiceTests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClient],
      providers: [My3rdPartyConnectedService]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const http = TestBed.get(HttpClient);

    http.delete("http://localhost:22213/api/somemethod").subscribe(() => {
…
    });
  }));
```

and the tests code goes. But when I run the tests I get:

> > Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

So how can I send requests inside my tests?

PS. Now, if you think I shouldn't be doing this in tests at all, you're wrong. These tests and the service actually do some work that involves third-part REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClient` is a service and cannot be put in `imports` array. You should replace it with `HttpClientModule` which provides `HttpClient`.

Comment: thank you! one should never write tests too late at night :)